# Why the trend to have SSID prefix start as "Direct-xx"?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, ssid, standards

I've noticed this trend that WIFI SSIDs now start with a prefix of "Direct-xx" (ex: Direct-EK-Bravia).

I've been unable to find anything that points to a new standard or requirement? Is this just say one company (say Intel) requiring all wifi endpoints to have a non changing prefix out of the 32 allowed characters?

Comment: It seems to be related to WiFi-networks from Sony Bravia TVs. But in general, if repeating strings in WiFi networks occur, this would typically linked to a common ISP in that area that hands out WiFi-Hotspots with their service.

Comment: no it isn't related to Sony, I've seen GM 4G hotspots start with this (latest model year) also printers, etc;  Please provide reference if you are providing an answer.

Comment: Well, I wrote "seems". Because that's what my Google search turned up. E.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMDgKUYAho0 "Direct" probably means something like "WiFi-Direct", where you connect directly to the device instead of having an accesspoint in the middle. But there is no enforcement of a specific SSID by a specific manufacturer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because those devices are setup for [WiFi-Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct).

> From a protocol point of view a Wi-Fi direct connection is established
>   using already existing mechanisms in a number of steps:
>
> In a first step, the two devices that are to connect directly have to
>   find each other. **This is done by sending standard Wi-Fi probe request
>   and response frames that include the Wi-Fi direct specific generic
>   SSID “DIRECT-”** and further Wi-Fi direct capability information. A
>   device answering with a probe response frame uses the same SSID and
>   includes vendor specific tagged information elements to also identify
>   itself as a Wi-Fi direct device and gives further information such as
>   its direct mode capabilities, device type and a name in readable
>   format that can be presented to the user.

[Source](http://mobilesociety.typepad.com/mobile_life/2013/01/wi-fi-direct-connection-establishment.html)

> The GO [Group Owner] starts to operate in Access Point mode, sending beacons with the negotiated SSID and a group formation bit set to 1, because the group formation has not yet been completed. **The SSID is standardized to be "DIRECT-xy..."** with xy being random characters/numbers and any postfix.

[Source](http://www.thinktube.com/tech/android/wifi-direct)